# Java - execute a .jarfile on a Linux server

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, shell

I have a java application with the content " executing a shell script" . I implemented a process builder to load a script (the script is located on my Linux server).

But I think there is something wrong with the path.

```
String cmd = "./sh test.sh"; 
ProcessBuilder process = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
Pocess p = process.start();
```

When I export this application as a jar file. And trying to run this on my Linux server. I get the message "cannot find file or directory" . When I run the shell script without a jar file it works. Is there something wrong with my path? Or why I get this message ? Just want to write an application which executes a script which is located on my Linux server. The script "test.sh" is stored in a folder which has the name "script" .

Thank you all.

Comment: Use the absolute path of `test.sh`.

Comment: `./sh` would imply that the shell `sh` is in the current directory; together with `test.sh`.

Comment: Sure `sh` is in your current directory? You usually want `/bin/sh` or `/bin/bash`

Comment: I also tried : /application/documents/script/test.sh             it is not working. @Eggen

Comment: What do you mean with /bin/sh..? @Gyro Gearless so sorry I am new in this

Comment: And why it is working when I am executing this without the jar file then it should also not work

Comment: `/bin/sh` is the most generic path to the shell executable and should work on every known unix system; on Linux this usually an alias (symlink) to `/bin/bash`, so this should work as well. Not sure why `./sh` works for your, this pretty much depends what your actual working directory is, and what `sh` executable is living there...

Comment: Ok what should I try now ? And maybe the process builder is not working right ?

Comment: try with String cmd = "/bin/sh /absolute/path/to/test.sh";
try to execute it without java first.

Comment: Thx @user2189998 it doesn't matter where the bin folder is and why "sh"? It's the command .. or is the command there in the bin? Like always ?

Comment: /bin/sh is the standard path for the sh command ( at least on ubuntu).